# Problem accessing server through .onion domain

Tags: django, tor

I tried to access a django server I was running on my virtual machine (Ubuntu 22.04.3) through an onion domain from my host OS(Windows 11)
First I installed tor and edited my torrc file and added these lines:

```
HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/hidden_service/
HiddenServicePort 8002 127.0.0.1:8002
```

then I saw my host name in /var/lib/tor/hidden_service/hostname.

```bash
root@soroush-VirtualBox:/home/soroush/Desktop/dw# cat /var/lib/tor/hidden_service/hostname
jn46lvmv4uu7bjfveoax.............rxv6ljid.onion
```

then I started a django project and edited settings.py to allow all host names

```py
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
```

then I started a django server on my 8002 port

```
python manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8002
```

then I tried to access my django server using the onion link. I copied the url in my tor browser on my host OS. but nothing loaded. I didn't even get any requests in my django server. I even tried using tor browser on my phone with a different network but that didn't work neither. the tor service is running and my django server works ok when I use my locan IP (127.0.0.1:8002). but when I try to access it through onion domain I can't.
what am I doing wrong?

I tried to access my django server through an onion domain but I couldn't

Comment: Since the hidden service's "external" port is 8002, did you try accessing it in Tor Browser using the address `http://jn46lvmv4uu7bjfveoax.............rxv6ljid.onion:8002` or without the port number? Since the hidden service port isn't 80, you'll need to specify the port number with the address in the browser. You probably want to use `HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:8002` instead.

Comment: You're welcome!